# Add authentication header via XMLHttpRequest Web API

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

There is a need to write an interceptor for XMLHttpRequest Web API, I have written it to this stage

```
const { serverUrl, bearerToken } = this.config;
const XMLHttpRequestOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (
    method: string,
    url: string
) {
    if (url.match(new RegExp(`^${serverUrl}`)) !== null && bearerToken) {
        this.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.OPENED) {
                this.setRequestHeader(
                    'Authorization',
                    `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
                );
            }
        };
    }
    return XMLHttpRequestOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Unfortunately, even though in dev console I see authentication header I still receive 401 server response.

[image]

What am I missing? Bearer token is 100% correct, so something is wrong with my implementation.

Comment: If it's showing up in the request headers there's probably an error with the server and not the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my solution was 100% correct, the problem was with CORS policy on proxy.